# python2 autocompletes file names on BASH shell, python3 does not

Tags: bash, python

When I type at the BASH terminal, I am accustomed to typing "python a_long_filename.py" but always using the "tab->" key to autocomplete the file name, which saves me time with typos.  This works with python2, but not with python3.

is there some package I can install, or some setting I can change, to enable the autocomplete for python3?

Comment: What is the output of `complete -p python3`?

Comment: output `bash: complete: python3: no completion specification` but `complete -p python` outputs the same

Comment: Just to clarify one thing, Bash is doing the completion. Read `help complete` for some info. So really the issue is that Bash autocompletes file names for python2 but not python3.

Comment: this is Ubuntu 17.10, with GNU bash, version 4.4.12(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)

Comment: After some testing, it seems like the completion settings don't get loaded until you try to use them. So try this in the terminal: type `python`, then a space, then press Tab, then erase it, and run `complete -p python python2 python3` (python and python2 added for good measure).

Comment: interesting, this changes the behavior.  Now when I do `complete -p python python2 python3` I get `complete -F _python python`, `complete -F _python python2`, `complete -F _python python3`, how can I get a specific setting for python3 to look for .py3 extension? because it is missing .py3 files when it autocompletes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As we discussed in the comments, you're trying to use Bash autocomplete on scripts with `.py3` extensions. The problem is, Bash will only autocomplete scripts with `.py` extensions.

I recommend using `.py` extensions even for Python 3 scripts, since `.py3` is non-standard. If the scripts require Python 3, you could...

- Use the shebang: `#!/usr/bin/env python3`
- Check if `sys.version_info.major == 3`

  - Or check if `>= 3`, to allow forwards compatibility
- Maybe use `from __future__ import ...` to allow backwards compatibility